# Batch replacing unidentified Characters in Unix that were created by macOS

Tags: linux, shell, file, unix, directory

On a Linux volume as part of a NAS with many TB of data some files were created from macOS and some of those files uploaded from macOS seem to include characters in filenames that cannot be reproduced via FTP or SMB file protocol. These files will appear as e.g. "picture_name001.jpg". Where the "" probably stands for a colon or slash.

I can search for "" and found out it applies to 2171 files in distributed locations on the volume. Way too much to manually find and correct each file name.

I thought I can connect to the NAS via SSH and simply loop through each directory doing an automated replace of the "" into "_", but this doesn't work because:

```
for file in **; do mv -- "$file" "${file///_}"; done
```

this attempt will throw back an error on the first item matching ** with:

```
mv: can't rename '120422_LAXJFK': No such file or directory
```

So obviously this substitute character displayed as "" is not the way to address the file or directory as it refers to a name that doesn't actually exists in the volume index.

(A) How do I find out if "120422_LAX:JFK" or "120422_LAX/JFK" is meant here, and (B) how do I escape these invalid characters to eventually be able to automatically rename all those names to for example "120422_LAX_JFK"?

Is there for example a way to get a numerical file ID from the name and then instruct to rename the file by number in case its name contains ""?

Comment: Those "" might be because there is a text encoding that is different on your system than on the filesystem that your NFS drive has. So basically what happens is that some chars overflow and there is no way of expressing that value on the encoding so they're replaced by a "" but they are indeed different chars, not exactly all are a "" so the values differ.

Comment: I understand this it's an invalid char, the volume is EXT, I wonder how uploading invalid files names was possible in the first place, but that's not the question here now. The question is how to loop though all directories and files and correct those that falsely appear as "".

Comment: Are you sure the filenames are wrong, or just that your terminal encoding is not displaying the names correctly?   Compare $LANG on MacOS and Linux

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that behind this "" can be different codes of symbols. When the system can't represent some characters (for example, given encoding is not supported), then it automatically replaced by some default character (in your case it is ""). But actually there is some code of the character, that should be in the name. BUT when you trying to do this `for file in **; do mv -- "$file" "${file///_}"; done` system can't recognize code, that symbol is "" is stands for.

I think this problem can be solved by changing the encoding of characters (they should be compatible and better the same) on both devices (mac and NAS)

Hope this would help

Comment: if I understand it correctly, this means it can only be solved on the system and protocol that uploaded those files? As I can not even download the directory or file "120422_LAXJFK". While FTP shows me "120422_LAXJFK" but then also says "No such file or directory" on attempting to download it. The server is up since 2012 and I cannot backtrace what software was used back in time causing these issues.